# Resuming activity from where it left if user killed the app manually

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am working on one application in which i move from Activity A(Main Activity) to Activity B to  Activity C. 
All of this is working fine but the problem occurs when user killed the app by removing it from Task tray.

To understand my problem say user moved from A to B and then C but before finishing the task in activity C user killed the app.
so when user again opens the app by pressing App icon i want to start the last activity C where user was when he killed the app instead of android default behavior of starting(Main Activity A) a fresh instance of app again.

What i have tried:

1) I tried using "onSaveInstanceState" and "onRestoreInstanceState", but i think they are used when orientation is changed or we go back by pressing back button.

2) I tried to save everything in "onPause" as onpause calls 99.99% times when activity destroyed and by using static flags i opens the last activity and it worked for me but i want some good example or technique to this work.

so can anyone help me on achieving the same..??

I request fellow members to provide code examples.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use sharedPreferences concept, save the activity name in sharedPreferences while opening of that activity, then check the sharedPreferences value while reopening the application. i think you got it!

Comment: you are on right track.

Comment: @W4R10CK thanks for your ans, your approach is correct but as i have already mentioned that i already tried this and it is working fine.
so don't mind but i am looking for some better work around and my ques is if anyone can provide some better approach to the problem.

Comment: @RajatPorwal, I would suggest to go for a bounty. You will find more attraction for this question.!

Answer (score 6):

Store the state in every `Activity`'s `@onPause()`.

So in every `Activity` you want:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("RESTART", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("last_left", getClass().getName());
    editor.commit();
}
```

And a `Shell` Activity which will be a Launcher, Main Activity:

```
public class Shell extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Class<?> classActivity;

        try {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("RESTART", MODE_PRIVATE);
            classActivity = Class.forName(prefs.getString("last_left", getClass.getName()));
        } 
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            classActivity = your_Activity1.class;
        }

        startActivity(new Intent(this, classActivity));
    }
}
```

[Source Modified]

Comment: this's a good solution but he also wants to save state. so i think in onResume you can save latest activity as you do in your solution and save state in onPause and restore if available.

Answer (score 1):

you can use SharedPreferences to store last user state.@onPause activity

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,  MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("state", "A/B/C");   
editor.commit();
```

OnResume Activity

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String stateApp = prefs.getString("state", null);

if (stateApp != null) {
   switc(stateApp){
      case 'A':
        // Go TO A activity
        break;

      case 'B':
        // Go TO B activity
        break;
      default:
       // Go TO C activity
        break;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Intent that was used to launch the activity is saved by the system when the process is about to be killed.Once the user returns into the app which has been killed, then the app is restored and the same Intent (Activity A in your case) is fired to launch the activity including all the extras that it might have.

Go for SharedPrefrences:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
refer the official documentation.

Comment: I think, that's only true when **system** kills the app. i.e. when it's low on resources.

Comment: Yes but the question says   "All of this is working fine but the problem occurs when user killed the app by removing it from Task tray.".Its similar to manual killing it from TaskTray.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sharedPreferences concept, save the activity name in sharedPreferences while the opening of that activity, then check the sharedPreferences value while reopening the application. I think you got it! 
sample tutorial link:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html